# How to show three buttons at the bottom of the screen like facebook in android?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I am working with android and I need to make an XML design in which I need to have three buttons at the bottom of my screen horizontally always. Just like facebook application in android, they have three buttons at the bottom of the screen (Status, Photo, Check In) - similarly I need to have three buttons as well always in my application.

What will be the design for this kind of layout?

I tried with the below XML design but it doesn't work somehow and they all are coming vertical -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/db1_root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/cow"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center|bottom"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="145dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center"
            android:text="ButtonA" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="145dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center"
            android:text="ButtonB" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="145dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center"
            android:text="ButtonC" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I just need to show three buttons at the bottom of the screen horizontally just like facebook shows always side by side (touching each other). Is this possible to do?

Button names can be - `ButtonA, ButtonB and ButtonC`

Comment: Why do you have 6 buttons declared at your layout?

Comment: You'd probably need a ScrollView with the buttons in a LinearLayout at the bottom - `buttons.layout_below` in the RelativeLayout.

Comment: They are vertical because you have `android:orientation="vertical"` on the LinearLayout. Change that to horizontal.

Comment: I see but will it come close to each other just like in facebook  application they come? I need to make them as close as possible, just trying to mimic the way facebook app looks.

Comment: Add empty `View`s on either side, and adjust the weights as necessary.

Comment: @MikeM. Can you provide an example if possible. It will help me a lot.

Comment: @user2809564 show below code, i think it help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below layout, i think its help you

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="cow"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="ButtonA" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="ButtonB" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="ButtonC" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you'll need to eventually adjust this, so I've left it pretty generic:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="2" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="2" />

    </LinearLayout>        

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use a layout with a Header-Footer-Content structure like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<!-- Header aligned to top -->
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/header"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    ...>
</RelativeLayout>

<!-- Footer aligned to bottom -->
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/footer"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ...>
   <!-- put your layout and buttons here -->
</RelativeLayout>

<!-- Content below header and above footer -->
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_above="@id/footer"
    android:layout_below="@id/header"
    ...>
</RelativeLayout>
```

You can remove pieces at your will.